# Profile specific properties with the same filename in different modules in Spring Boot app

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven

I have a Maven project with Spring Boot (2.3.x). Parent module has core library, which contains an application-cache.properties:

```
cache.value1=aaa
cache.value2=bbb
```

I've added to my project file with the same name (application-cache.properties) in order to enable some application-specific properties using one spring profile.

```
additional.value=ccc
```

application.properties:

```
spring.profiles.include=cache
```

My assumption was that both files will be merged like:

```
cache.value1=aaa
cache.value2=bbb
additional.value=ccc
```

But looks like a property file in my project is ignored. Is it possible to change such behavior to 'merge mode'?

Answer (score 0):

There's no support for merging multiple configuration files with the same name. The files are loaded from the classpath and, as with class loading, the first entry on the classpath wins.

> spring.profiles.include=application-cache.properties

Not directly related to merging, but this doesn't look right. To load a configuration file named `application-cache.properties` the `cache` profile should be included:

```
spring.profiles.include=cache
```

Comment: Thanks, I corrected copy-pasted value in spring.profiles.include. So in other words in my case application.properties will be _updated_ with application-cache.properties, while application-cache.properties will be picked up acordig the order in classpath, correct?

Comment: Profile-specific configuration files take precedence over "standard" configuration files. With the `cache` profile active, both `application.properties` and `application-cache.properties` will be loaded. For any properties that exist in both files, the value in `application-cache.properties` will be used. If there are multiple `application-cache.properties` files on the classpath, only the file that appears first will be used.

Comment: Thank you very much for the clarification.